# Method containg 2 parameters should be replaced with 3 parameters which is declared more than 100 times

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method which is used globally across my application.It will look like :

```
public void AddData(string Key,Object Val)
{
    ....code goes here
}
```

Now I am calling this `AddData()` method around 100 times in my application at serveral places:

```
objData.AddData("key1",obj1);
objData.AddData("key2",obj2);
objData.AddData("key3",obj3);
```

Later i have added an additional parameter named `Region`:

```
public void AddData(string Key,Object Val,string Region)
{
    ....code goes here
}
```

Now I need to change all the 100 methods parameters by adding a new parameter. Or else it will give the compiler error "No overload of method AddData takes 2 arguments"...

Is there any way to make all these method calls work with the new method signature?

Comment: `Search and Replace`

Comment: Do you need 100 different values, depending on each case, or do you just need to stuff in a 3rd parameter value that is the same for all the 100 you currently have?

Comment: @Lasse No the third parameter value is different for different methods..

Answer (score 3):

Give it a default value, so the callers don't have to specify the third parameter:

```
public void AddData(string key, Object val, string region = null)
{
    // code goes here
}
```

Alternatively, create an overload:

```
public void AddData(string key, Object val)
{
    AddData(key, val, null);
}

public void AddData(string key, Object val, string region)
{
    // code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply.But according to your solution also..i need to change all my 100 methods by calling the additional method with three parameters.

Comment: What makes you think so? Did you try it? The point is that you don't have to alter the calls, using either suggestion. See [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). You just have to come up with a decent default value, which I provided as `= null`.

Comment: Ok i got it.No need to call it 100 times.But if i want to pass different value instead of default value??

Comment: Yeah, then you need to alter the call statements.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply..I will check for alternatives then.Let me know if any other alternatives are there..

Comment: There are no alternatives. If you want a different value on every call, you have to specify it. If you want the default value to be "foo", use `string region = "foo"`. Callers can override the default by providing a value (`AddData("key", "value", "bar")`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have C# 4 (in Visual Studio 2010 or later), you can use a default value for the third parameter.

```
public void AddData(string key, object val, string region = null)
{
    // etc
    if (region != null)
    {
        // etc
    }
    // etc
}
```

For previous versions of C#, you can overload the method:

```
public void AddData(string key, object val)
{
    // Use the new overload, passing null for the third parameter.
    AddData(key, object, null);
}

public void AddData(string key, object val, string region)
{
    // etc
    if (region != null)
    {
        // etc
    }
    // etc
}
```

Or you can use search and replace in the Visual Studio editor.